# changing value of extern variable outside of file where it was declared

Tags: c, extern

I'm trying to figure out how I can have an extern variable across multiple files and be able to change it globally, when I change its value in one file, I expected it to change in all the other files.

For example:

header.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int val = 0;
```

file1.c:

```
#include "header.h"
extern int val;

void foo() {
    printf("%d\n", val);
}
```

file2.c:

```
#include "header.h"
extern int val;

void foo() {
    val = 1;
}
```

So I expected that if I ran file1 I would get 0 printed in the console,  but if I ran file2 first and then file1, I would get 1 printed out.

Am I wrong about the way extern works?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?  How are you "running" these individual files?

Comment: Do you have any `main` function in your source code? If not, it shouldn't even compile.

Comment: If both source files are linked together, you'll have issues with conflicting definitions of `foo`.

Comment: You have it backwards.  It should be extern in the header file, and declared in one C file.

Comment: I'm compiling them in a makefile, with just gcc -o filename filename.c. Whether i run file1 first or file2, when file1 runs, the value 0 gets printed out

Comment: yes i do have a main, i also have more files, this was just a simplified example to try to understand how i can change the variable val from different files.

Comment: no they are not linked, they are supposed to be run separately.

Comment: There is no way to use variables in a separate process without using shared memory.

Comment: It's good to simplify an example. But the example should also be complete. Fix a [mre]

Comment: `they are supposed to be run separately` But you stated that `when compiled together`.

Comment: yeah that was my mistake,  they aren't linked.

Comment: If you *really* need to share variable between two separate programs, you have to use shared memory (which is platform-specific) and also proper synchronization (like in multithreading, but harder). `extern` is only suitable if you need to share it between two files that are parts of the same program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Assuming that you are compiling both file1.c and file2.c into a single binary.

   For sharing variable between different files you can also use #defines and #ifdef macros.

   i. declare `#define __MAIN__` (this is just for example, it could be anything) at start of the files before all include statement in one of the .c file

   ii. in header.h you can do the following,

   ```
   #ifdef __MAIN__
       int val = 0;
   #else
       extern int val;
   ```
2. Assuming that both file1.c and file2.c will be compiled into different binary and while running both will act as 2 different process then:

   i. There are IPC techniques for communications between 2 process, for your case shared memory would be appropriate.

   ii. You can use System V shared memory or POSIX shared memory, following links are here for reference.

   System V: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ipc-shared-memory/

   POSIX : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/posix-shared-memory-api/